# How to debug excessive iPhone data usage?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

I'm in the UK, and recently changed from a pre-pay carrier (GiffGaff) to EE. My data usage with GiffGaff was about 100-125 MB every two weeks; with EE, I've used nearly 250 MB in the first 5 days. My usage is the same: email, web, Twitter, and some Maps. (Both with my last two weeks with GiffGaff, and these past few days, I've used Maps on a driving trip.)

So I'm trying to figure out what's going on. I know I'm not using that much data, but something on the phone is using data. This is clearly a carrier issue; either the carrier settings or something that has changed. I know you can access Console logs via Xcode, but I don't see anything helpful there.

Does anyone know how I can debug this? I'm ready to go to EE and cancel my contract, because at this rate, the data will cost me a fortune.

Comment: Have you upgraded to iOS 8?  In the mobile data section, you can go into 'system services' at the bottom and look at the different services and how much data they're using.

Answer (score 1):

Some networks measure data use in different ways to others to get more profit out of it so maybe consider changing to a network that measures data as less?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Onavo Count](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onavo-count-data-usage-manager/id543547474?mt=8) or [Onavo Extend](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onavo-data-usage-get-more/id423545287?mt=8) apps could help you. There is also a list of [Data Usage Monitor apps](http://voip.about.com/od/voipbandwidth/tp/Data-Usage-Monitor-Apps-For-Your-Iphone-And-Ipad.htm).

Comment: Onava Count showed me that no app was using data; ie, it was the OS itself. I downloaded ActMonitor, which showed me cumulative data, incrementing in real time, and eventually found that if I turned off push, data stopped. After a few times of trying to turn it on then off, the problem disappeared. I can only assume that there was some sort of carrier problem with push, which sorted out after a few days.